# PHP Symfony 2.3: How to access constraints of form fields in twig templates and programmatically?

Tags: php, forms, constraints, symfony-2.3

I am currently creating lots of forms with symfony and I want to mark field labels with an asterisk (*) if they have a "Not Blank" constraint automatically. So I need to determine weather there exists that kind of constraint for a specific field or not no matter if the for is submitted or not.

Currently I have the following code for adding a class to the surrounding `div` if a form field contains errors after submitting the form.

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="{% if errors|length > 0 %} error{% endif %}">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }} {% if name == 'shareValue' %}&nbsp;<span id="shareValue_label"></span>{% endif %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

I'd like to have something similar to `{% if errors|length > 0 %} error{% endif %}` but with testing if the "Not Blank" constraint is applied to the field or not instead of testing for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make a difference for you between "Non blank" constraint and require attribute? If not, did you read this section of [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels) ?